# Replace NA with the nearest value based on another variable, while keeping NA for observation which doesn't have non-missing neighbour

Tags: r, na, missing-data, nearest-neighbor

Here I have a data that looks like this:

```
year <- c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010)
x <- c(1,2,3,NA,5,NA,NA,NA,9,10)
dat <- data.frame(year, x)
```

1. I want to replace `NA` with the nearest neighbor according to the year variable.

For example, The fourth place of the data (the first `NA`) takes the value from its left neighbor rather than its right neighbor because its year "2003" is closer to "2002" instead of "2005"

2. I want to leave the `NA` there when it does not have nearest nonNA neighbor.

For example, the seventh place of the data (the third NA) will still be NA because it does not have non-NA neighbor.

After imputing, the resulting x should be `1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, NA, 9, 9, 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to make use of `case_when` from `tidyverse`. Essentially, if the previous row has a closer year and is not `NA`, then return `x` from that row. If not, then choose the row below. Or if the year is closer above but there is an `NA`, then return the row below. Then, same for if the row below has a closer year, but has an `NA`, then return the row above. If a row does not have an `NA`, then just return `x`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  mutate(x = case_when(is.na(x) & !is.na(lag(x)) & year - lag(year) < lead(year) - year ~ lag(x),
                       is.na(x) & !is.na(lead(x)) & year - lag(year) > lead(year) - year ~ lead(x),
                       is.na(x) & is.na(lag(x)) ~ lead(x),
                       is.na(x) & is.na(lead(x)) ~ lag(x),
                       TRUE ~ x))
```

**Output**

```
   year  x
1  2000  1
2  2001  2
3  2002  3
4  2003  3
5  2005  5
6  2006  5
7  2007 NA
8  2008  9
9  2009  9
10 2010 10
```

Answer (score 0):

A method using `imap()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  mutate(new = imap_dbl(x, ~ {
    if(is.na(.x)) {
      dist <- abs(year[-.y] - year[.y])
      res <- x[-.y][dist == min(dist, na.rm = TRUE)]
      if(all(is.na(res))) NA else na.omit(res)
    } else .x
  }))

#    year  x new
# 1  2000  1   1
# 2  2001  2   2
# 3  2002  3   3
# 4  2003 NA   3
# 5  2005  5   5
# 6  2006 NA   5
# 7  2007 NA  NA
# 8  2008 NA   9
# 9  2009  9   9
# 10 2010 10  10
```

Answer (score 0):

a `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
# first or last NA in a sequence of NA's?
# we need to convert these back to NA later in the process
dat[is.na(x) & is.na(shift(x, type = "lag")) & is.na(shift(x, type = "lead")), excl := "1"]
# rolling self-join on x
dat[is.na(x), x := dat[!is.na(x), ][.SD, x, on = .(year), roll = "nearest"]]
# set x back to NA if needed, remove the excl column
dat[excl == 1, x := NA][, excl := NULL][]
#    year  x
# 1: 2000  1
# 2: 2001  2
# 3: 2002  3
# 4: 2003  3
# 5: 2005  5
# 6: 2006  5
# 7: 2007 NA
# 8: 2008  9
# 9: 2009  9
#10: 2010 10
```