# Replace an NA in a column with it's nearest, in terms of a date column, non-NA with a condition, in R

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I have a dataframe similar to the one below - my actual being larger and grouped - and was wondering how to impute the NAs with the nearest non NA for an integer variable, in terms of date, that is less than 30 days from the observation - before or after. When there is a tie, I want to opt for the earlier rather than the later date. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71897704/replace-na-with-the-nearest-value-based-on-another-variable-while-keeping-na-fo), but it doesn't account for consecutive NAs.

Any help would be really appreciated!

```
df <- data.frame(
  dates = c("2023-09-01", "2023-09-02", "2023-09-05", "2023-09-06", "2023-09-10",
            "2023-09-11", "2023-09-14", "2023-09-16", "2023-09-20", "2023-09-27", "2023-09-28"),
  x = c(10, NA, 20, NA, NA, 30, NA, NA, NA, 40, NA)
)

# desired output for the x column

x= c(10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40)
```

Comment: Hi! May you specify 1) 30 days prior or after the observation? 2) Integer or numeric values? 3) what is the math for comuting the value - mean / rep etc? What is your desired output for the given sample?

Comment: Thanks for these! I wasn't sure what you meant by question 3? I think I've answereed the rest though. Also, added an additional point to when an NA is equal distance to two non NA values.

Comment: Which value to prefer for today (NA) if we have values for tomorrow (say 10) and yeterday (say 20)?

Comment: I'd need the value from yesterday if there is equal distance between the two nearest non NAs

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% mutate(dates = as.Date(dates))  # type cast from Q sample

ddd <- filter(df, !is.na(x)) %>% pull(dates) # vector of dates for which x'es are available

useDatediff <- function(d){       # find nearest date for which value is present
  aftr <- min(ddd[ddd >= d] - d)  # and return the days difference (+) after or (-) before
  bfr <- min(d - ddd[ddd <= d])
    if (aftr > 30 && bfr > 30) return(0) # after left_join x will be NA
    if (bfr <= aftr) { # bfr is prevailing
      -bfr 
    } else {
      aftr
    } 
}


df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(useDatediff = useDatediff(dates)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(useDate = dates + useDatediff) %>% 
  left_join(df, by = c("useDate" = "dates")) %>% 
  transmute(dates, 
            x = coalesce(x.x, x.y))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 11 × 2
# Rowwise: 
   dates          x
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 2023-09-01    10
 2 2023-09-02    10
 3 2023-09-05    20
 4 2023-09-06    20
 5 2023-09-10    30
 6 2023-09-11    30
 7 2023-09-14    30
 8 2023-09-16    30
 9 2023-09-20    40
10 2023-09-27    40
11 2023-09-28    40
```

Comment: @Martin I edited the answer to suit 30 days constraint