# Replace an NA in a column with it's nearest, in terms of a date column, within group, non-NA, with a condition, in R

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I have a dataframe similar to the one below - my actual being larger - and was wondering how to impute the NAs with the nearest non NA, within group, for an integer variable - nearest in terms of date - that is less than 30 days from the observation, before or after. When there is a tie, I want to opt for the earlier rather than the later date. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71897704/replace-na-with-the-nearest-value-based-on-another-variable-while-keeping-na-fo), but it doesn't account for consecutive NAs.

Any help would be really appreciated!

```
df <- data.frame(
  id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
  dates = c("2023-09-01", "2023-09-02", "2023-09-05", "2023-09-06","2023-09-10" , "2023-09-11",
            "2023-09-12", "2023-09-14", "2023-09-16", "2023-09-20", "2023-09-27", "2023-09-28"),
  x = c(10, NA, NA, 20, 20, NA, 30, 15, NA, NA, 40, NA)
)

# desired output

x1 <- c(10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 15, 15, 15, 40, 40)
```

Comment: why is `x1[6]` 30, it should be 20, no? since there is a tie and one should take the earliest date

Comment: Ah sorry! thanks for catching that, I'll edit accordingly

Comment: Related post https://stackoverflow.com/q/28072542/680068

Answer (score 3):

The sample data does not challenge the prospect of looking *forward* for the nearest date. Some of the automated rolling/nearest fills start to work, but none of them inherently honor the "30 days limit" needed. For example, in `data.table`-speak, `roll="nearest"` will always match the closest date but not look at the date-difference to see if it is within the constraint.

I'll suggest alternate data that has rows that need to look forward, backward, and one that should match nothing, and I'll assume a difference of 8 days (vice 30) for a simple example:

```r
DT2 <- data.table(id=1L, dates=as.Date("2023-09-01")+c(0,1,5,6,7,15), x=replace(1:6, c(3,5,6), NA), expect=c(1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA))[]
DT2
#       id      dates     x expect
#    <int>     <Date> <int>  <int>
# 1:     1 2023-09-01     1      1
# 2:     1 2023-09-02     2      2
# 3:     1 2023-09-06    NA      4  # matches row 4
# 4:     1 2023-09-07     4      4
# 5:     1 2023-09-08    NA      4  # matches row 4
# 6:     1 2023-09-16    NA     NA  # too far, no match
```

Noteworthy is that row 3 is within the limit of both rows 2 and 4, but since row 4 is closer, its value should be used.

Using `data.table`,  I think this works.

```r
fun <- function(dt, val, lim) {
  z <- abs(outer(dt, replace(dt, is.na(val), NA), `-`))
  z[z > lim] <- NA
  val[apply(z, 1, function(y) which.min(y)[1])]
}
DT2[, x1 := fun(dates, x, lim = 8), by = .(id)]
DT2
#       id      dates     x expect    x1
#    <int>     <Date> <int>  <int> <int>
# 1:     1 2023-09-01     1      1     1
# 2:     1 2023-09-02     2      2     2
# 3:     1 2023-09-06    NA      4     4
# 4:     1 2023-09-07     4      4     4
# 5:     1 2023-09-08    NA      4     4
# 6:     1 2023-09-16    NA     NA    NA
```

Components of that `fun`ction:

- `outer(..)` calculates the date differences; since we do not want to match against dates with `NA` values, inside of this we use `replace(dt, is.na(val), NA)` to NA-out those dates (and then `abs(.)` the whole thing)
- a natural "goodness" of this is that the diagonal of this is either `0` (self minus self is 0) which is self-referential when it comes to assigning values, or `NA` (when `x` is `NA`), so a non-`NA` value will never be replaced with something else
- in `z` (date-differences matrix), we replace values with differences over `lim` with `NA`
- at this point, all values in `z` should be either `NA` (no match can be made) or a positive value less than or equal to `lim`, where `0` will always be the least found by `which.min`
- because each row of `z` corresponds to an output value we want, we'll use `apply(z, 1, ..)`, which will iterate over each row
- if we used `which.min(y)` itself, then when there are no non-`NA` values it will return `c()`, which will break what we need; however, adding `[1]` to that *forces* it to return `NA` in that case, and a single integer in all other cases, so `which.min(y)[1]` will return which column of `z` has the lowest date-difference or `NA` otherwise
- (anything indexed with `[NA]` will just be `NA`)

Demonstrated on your original data using a max-difference of 2 days,

```r
DT <- as.data.table(df)[, dates := as.Date(dates)][]
DT
#        id      dates     x expect
#     <num>     <Date> <num>  <num>
#  1:     1 2023-09-01    10     10
#  2:     1 2023-09-02    NA     10
#  3:     1 2023-09-05    NA     20
#  4:     1 2023-09-06    20     20
#  5:     2 2023-09-10    20     20
#  6:     2 2023-09-11    NA     20
#  7:     2 2023-09-12    30     30
#  8:     3 2023-09-14    15     15
#  9:     3 2023-09-16    NA     15
# 10:     3 2023-09-20    NA     15
# 11:     4 2023-09-27    40     40
# 12:     4 2023-09-28    NA     40

DT[, x1 := fun(dates, x, lim = 30), by = .(id)]
DT
#        id      dates     x expect    x1
#     <num>     <Date> <num>  <num> <num>
#  1:     1 2023-09-01    10     10    10
#  2:     1 2023-09-02    NA     10    10
#  3:     1 2023-09-05    NA     20    20
#  4:     1 2023-09-06    20     20    20
#  5:     2 2023-09-10    20     20    20
#  6:     2 2023-09-11    NA     20    20
#  7:     2 2023-09-12    30     30    30
#  8:     3 2023-09-14    15     15    15
#  9:     3 2023-09-16    NA     15    15
# 10:     3 2023-09-20    NA     15    15
# 11:     4 2023-09-27    40     40    40
# 12:     4 2023-09-28    NA     40    40
```

We don't strictly need `data.table` here. (Note that a previous version of this answer used `fcoalesce` and had translations for `dplyr::coalesce` and a base-R variant, but `fun` no longer needs it, so those extra steps have been removed.)

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(dates = as.Date(dates)) %>%
  mutate(x1 = fun(dates, x, lim = 30), .by = id)
#    id      dates  x expect x1
# 1   1 2023-09-01 10     10 10
# 2   1 2023-09-02 NA     10 10
# 3   1 2023-09-05 NA     20 20
# 4   1 2023-09-06 20     20 20
# 5   2 2023-09-10 20     20 20
# 6   2 2023-09-11 NA     20 20
# 7   2 2023-09-12 30     30 30
# 8   3 2023-09-14 15     15 15
# 9   3 2023-09-16 NA     15 15
# 10  3 2023-09-20 NA     15 15
# 11  4 2023-09-27 40     40 40
# 12  4 2023-09-28 NA     40 40
```

and base R:

```r
# convert to Date-class
df$dates <- as.Date(df$dates)
# prefill, needed for `split(..)<-` to work
df$x1 <- NA

split(df, df$id) <- split(df, df$id) |>
  lapply(function(X) transform(X, x1 = fun(dates, x, lim = 8)))
df
#    id      dates  x expect x1
# 1   1 2023-09-01 10     10 10
# 2   1 2023-09-02 NA     10 10
# 3   1 2023-09-05 NA     20 20
# 4   1 2023-09-06 20     20 20
# 5   2 2023-09-10 20     20 20
# 6   2 2023-09-11 NA     20 20
# 7   2 2023-09-12 30     30 30
# 8   3 2023-09-14 15     15 15
# 9   3 2023-09-16 NA     15 15
# 10  3 2023-09-20 NA     15 15
# 11  4 2023-09-27 40     40 40
# 12  4 2023-09-28 NA     40 40
```